# Create Nested List from tabular data

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, rule

Im trying to create a nested list from tabular data, then onward into a nested association.
I can get part way with the help of this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3070) but it only works for the first level.  Repeated use of this approach doesn't seem to work.

```
list=  {{"Category", "Detail", "Value"}, {"Cat1", "detail1", 23},
{"Cat1", "detail2", 27}, {"Cat1", "detail3", 13}, {"Cat2", "detail4",15}, 
{"Cat2", "detail5", 35}, {"Cat3", "Detail6", 56}};

list // TableForm

(*  tabular data result *)
```

First level of data.

```
Thread[list[[2 ;;, 2]] -> #] & /@ {list[[2 ;;, 3]]} // ToAssociations

 {<|detail1->23,detail2->27,detail3->13,detail4->15,detail5->35,Detail6->56|>}
```

Required result

```
{<| Cat1-> <|detail1->23,detail2->27,detail3->13|>|>,
<| Cat2-> <|detail4->15,detail5->35|>|>,
<| Cat3-> <|Detail6->56|>|>}
```

**Update** is it possible to come up with something that works for N levels of nesting?

Eg 3 levels of nesting

```
list = {{"BigCat", "Category", "Detail", "Value"}, {"BigCat", "Cat1", 
   "detail1", 23}, {"BigCat", "Cat1", "detail2", 27}, {"BigCat", 
   "Cat1", "detail3", 13}, {"BigCat", "Cat2", "detail4", 
   15}, {"BigCat", "Cat2", "detail5", 35}, {"LittleCat", "Cat3", 
   "Detail6", 56}}
```

Comment: For your new updated list you can use `GroupBy[Rest@list, First -> Rest, 
 GroupBy[#, First -> Rest, Association[Rule @@@ (#)] &] &]`. This could be extended to an arbitrary number of levels by using [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html).

Comment: Related: [(83507)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83507/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my answer to [Handy / flexible directory tree operations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83507/handy-flexible-directory-tree-operations/83514#83514) with minor modification:

```
fn[x_List] := GroupBy[x, First -> Rest, fn]

fn[{{x_}}] := x
```

Tested on your two lists, named `list1` and `list2` respectively:

```
fn[Rest @ list1]
```

> ```
> <|"Cat1" -> <|"detail1" -> 23, "detail2" -> 27, "detail3" -> 13|>, 
>  "Cat2" -> <|"detail4" -> 15, "detail5" -> 35|>, "Cat3" -> <|"Detail6" -> 56|>|>
> ```

```
fn[Rest @ list2]
```

> ```
> <|"BigCat" -> <|"Cat1" -> <|"detail1" -> 23, "detail2" -> 27, "detail3" -> 13|>, 
>    "Cat2" -> <|"detail4" -> 15, "detail5" -> 35|>|>, 
>  "LittleCat" -> <|"Cat3" -> <|"Detail6" -> 56|>|>|>
> ```

Comment: Should have thought about that ! Terse and much more readable.

Comment: could you just give me a hint on what the overloading of fn enables?  Does it enable the recursion for `list2` or is it just a dummy reduction function for GroupBy?

Comment: @Gordon I may mistake what you mean by "overloading" -- the use of `fn` within `GroupBy` indeed enables recursion.  The definition `fn[{{x_}}] := x` provides a termination parameter for the recursion.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think you understood me first time. :) Essentially overloading in this instance is providing multiple definitions of the same function, that differ by type.

Comment: @Gordon Okay.  Thanks for the Accept!

Answer (score 6):

I guess this is what you want. Using `GroupBy` and then combining them as `Association` will do the trick.

```
GroupBy[Rest@list, First -> Rest, Association[Rule @@@ #] &]
```

Resulting in

```
{<| Cat1-> <|detail1->23,detail2->27,detail3->13|>|>,
<| Cat2-> <|detail4->15,detail5->35|>|>,
<| Cat3-> <|Detail6->56|>|>}
```

Comment: This is spot on however I've moved the goal posts slightly (sorry).  Is it possible to do it for N levels of nesting?

Answer (score 4):

If you need a method for **any** levels of nesting (as mentionned in your update), maybe try something like this:

```
groupbyNest[x_List] := 
 GroupBy[x, First -> Rest, groupbyNest] /; Last@Dimensions@x > 1

groupbyNest[x_List] := First@Flatten@x /; Last@Dimensions@x == 1
```

Then for example, given

```
list = {{"BigCat", "Category", "Detail", "Value"}, {"BigCat", "Cat1", 
   "detail1", 23}, {"BigCat", "Cat1", "detail2", 27}, {"BigCat", 
   "Cat1", "detail3", 13}, {"BigCat", "Cat2", "detail4", 
   15}, {"BigCat", "Cat2", "detail5", 35}, {"LittleCat", "Cat3", 
   "Detail6", 56}}
```

just

```
groupbyNest@Rest@list
```

returns

> <|"BigCat" -> <|"Cat1" -> <|"detail1" -> 23, "detail2" -> 27, 
>        "detail3" -> 13|>,     "Cat2" -> <|"detail4" -> 15, "detail5" -> 35|>|>,   "LittleCat" -> <|"Cat3" -> <|"Detail6" -> 56|>|>|>

Comment: You have my vote for using the same method I did.  I hope you don't mind that I also posted an answer.  I feel justified in doing so as I used the method before and I also chose a slightly more terse definition.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's fine ! Did not know about your previous post about that. Actually here, I was wondering how to make the answer as general as possible, in particular concerning the last step when there is no need to `GroupBy` anymore. In the OP's example the last elements are just numbers (`23`, `56`, ...) but it could be anything like a list  (`{23,56,...}`), ... or a list of lists of lists ...(which is not handled by my approach because of the `Flatten`).

Answer (score 3):

In general, the transformation you ask for can be done, for example, along the lines I outlined in [my answer on Associations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54493/81) (section on example database).

#### Transforming to a list of associations

To use the solution from tha post verbatim (more or less), we will need an auxiliary function to transform your data to a list of associations first:

```
toAssocList =
  Composition[
    Map[Association],
    Transpose,
    Map[Thread[First[#] -> Rest[#]] &],
    Transpose
  ]
```

so that

```
assocs = toAssocList@list

(* 
   {
     <|"BigCat" -> "BigCat", "Category" -> "Cat1", "Detail" -> "detail1", "Value" -> 23|>, 
     <|"BigCat" -> "BigCat", "Category" -> "Cat1", "Detail" -> "detail2", "Value" -> 27|>, 
     <|"BigCat" -> "BigCat", "Category" -> "Cat1", "Detail" -> "detail3", "Value" -> 13|>, 
     <|"BigCat" -> "BigCat", "Category" -> "Cat2", "Detail" -> "detail4",  "Value" -> 15|>, 
     <|"BigCat" -> "BigCat", "Category" -> "Cat2", "Detail" -> "detail5", "Value" -> 35|>, 
     <|"BigCat" -> "LittleCat", "Category" -> "Cat3", "Detail" -> "Detail6", "Value" -> 56|>
 }
*)
```

#### Transformation to the hierarchical structure

Using the function `pushUpNested` from the mentioned post, we can generate the corresponding tramnsformation:

```
transform = pushUpNested[{{"BigCat"}, {"Category"}, {"Detail"},{"Value"}}]

(*

 Map[
   Map[
     Map[Map[Identity]@*GroupBy[#1[[Sequence[Key["Value"]]]] &]]@* 
     GroupBy[#1[[Sequence[Key["Detail"]]]] &]
   ]@*
   GroupBy[#1[[Sequence[Key["Category"]]]] &]
 ]@*
 GroupBy[#1[[Sequence[Key["BigCat"]]]] &]
```

which we can use:

```
transform@assocs

(* <|"BigCat" -> <|"Cat1" -> <|"detail1" -> <|23 -> {<|"BigCat" -> "BigCat", "Category" -> "Cat1", "Detail" -> "detail1", 
      "Value" -> 23|>}|>, 
 "detail2" -> <|27 -> {<|"BigCat" -> "BigCat", 
      "Category" -> "Cat1", "Detail" -> "detail2", 
      "Value" -> 27|>}|>, 
 "detail3" -> <|13 -> {<|"BigCat" -> "BigCat", 
      "Category" -> "Cat1", "Detail" -> "detail3", 
      "Value" -> 13|>}|>|>, 
 "Cat2" -> <|"detail4" -> <|15 -> {<|"BigCat" -> "BigCat", 
      "Category" -> "Cat2", "Detail" -> "detail4", 
      "Value" -> 15|>}|>, 
 "detail5" -> <|35 -> {<|"BigCat" -> "BigCat", 
      "Category" -> "Cat2", "Detail" -> "detail5", 
      "Value" -> 35|>}|>|>|>, 
"LittleCat" -> <|"Cat3" -> <|"Detail6" -> <|56 -> {<|"BigCat" -> 
       "LittleCat", "Category" -> "Cat3", "Detail" -> "Detail6", 
      "Value" -> 56|>}|>|>|>|>

*)
```

#### Cleaning up

It remains now to remove the "leafs" in this construction (the lowest-level values):

```
Map[First@*Keys, transform@assocs, {3}]

(* 
    <|"BigCat" -> 
        <|
           "Cat1" -> <|"detail1" -> 23, "detail2" -> 27,"detail3" -> 13|>, 
           "Cat2" -> <|"detail4" -> 15, "detail5" -> 35|>
        |>, 
      "LittleCat" -> <|"Cat3" -> <|"Detail6" -> 56|>|>
    |>
*)
```

#### Notes

I don't claim this solution is the most efficient, but I think it illustrates a pretty general scheme, and a different, higher-level way to make such transformations - through transform generators. This can be used for much more complex cases. In fact, as I noted in the linked answer, `Dataset` is using a similar (but much more complex) scheme to generate queries.